# Is there any way to start services from docker image, can't start pre-enabled systemd images (255)

Tags: linux, systemd, docker, services, privileges

I want to start some service from this [section](https://github.com/mintme-com/pool/wiki/Detailed-guide-about-Webchain-pool-installation#setting-up-services) tryed everything up until now and run out of ideas. I have a debian 10 VPS with no root access and need i have been looking forward to find another way how to do it.

On my VPS that i have i can install ubuntu and have no problem installing pre enabled systemd images i have been using this images : [JREI/Systemd-debian](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrei/systemd-debian), [JREI/Systemd-ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrei/systemd-ubuntu) and worked like a charm.

But in this case of VPS i can download with no issue but when i start it with commands :

**JREI/Systemd-debian described like on the develeoper site :**

```
   1. Run the container as a daemon

docker run -d --name systemd-debian --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-debian

or if it doesn't work

docker run -d --name systemd-debian --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-debian

  2.  Enter to the container

docker exec -it systemd-debian sh

  3.  Remove the container

docker rm -f systemd-debian
```

**JREI/Systemd-ubuntu described like on the develeoper site :**

```
    Run the container as a daemon

docker run -d --name systemd-ubuntu --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-ubuntu

or if it doesn't work

docker run -d --name systemd-ubuntu --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-ubuntu

    Enter to the container

docker exec -it systemd-ubuntu sh

    Remove the container

docker rm -f systemd-ubuntu
```

**But on this case that i have when i use command it's just print it like this :**

```
$ sudo docker run -d --name systemd-debian --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-debian
Unable to find image 'jrei/systemd-debian:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from jrei/systemd-debian
e756f3fdd6a3: Already exists
cc35b3a645b1: Pull complete
a2c2f4c9293b: Pull complete
16d72487363d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:dcd311f3192a25be0ff12b2f3b283c00eb51f66e2716c498b8e5c15a35085075
Status: Downloaded newer image for jrei/systemd-debian:latest
32e100dfef82209a0e7810be37fbff837cbe1e69d718b4eb4ceba69e7161be24
```

Nothing happends and the container exit automaticly with error (255)

**Used the logs command and i can see this :**

```
Failed to create /init.scope control group: Read-only file system
Failed to allocate manager object: Read-only file system
[!!!!!!] Failed to allocate manager object.
Exiting PID 1...
```

Never had any kind of problems with pre enabled systemd images before or runing this command but on this VPS i have this kind of problem which is making me scratch my head.

**Then started doing Dockerfile :**

```
FROM debian

ENV container docker
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Enable systemd.
RUN apt-get update ; \
    apt-get install -y systemd systemd-sysv; \
    apt-get clean ; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* ; \
    rm -rf /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/* ; \
    rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/* ; \
    rm -rf /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/* ; \
    rm -rf /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev* ; \
    rm -rf /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl* ; \
    rm -rf /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-tmpfiles-setup* ; \
    rm -rf /lib/systemd/system/systemd-update-utmp*

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

**And used this command to start build it up :**

```
sudo docker build -t kastra .
```

**Then this to run it :**

```
sudo docker run  --name mintmefinal --tty   --privileged   --volume /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro  kastra
```

**And i am straight to this error again :**

```
##################################### LOGS ###################################
systemd 247.3-7 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=unified)
Detected virtualization docker.
Detected architecture x86-64.

Welcome to Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)!

Set hostname to <526d66e546b7>.
Failed to create /init.scope control group: Read-only file system
Failed to allocate manager object: Read-only file system
[!!!!!!] Failed to allocate manager object.
Exiting PID 1...
```

And there it came to me  maybe i am doing something that doesn't require this much work but just to ask maybe it's another way, something that i don't know and would be very grateful if someone would help me solve this problem it's making me crazy.

Is there anyway else to start those services without systemctl, or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: I am stuck too. I am running Debian/bullseye and just want to start JREI/Systemd-debian but fail to do so.
Have you tried `--volume /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw`? (It does not work for me, but I am curious if this somehow improves your situation).